# Como aplicar máscara em um campo neste formato "000 000 000 0"?

Tags: javascript

Peguei este código pronto de máscara, mas gostaria de adaptar formato `000 000 000 0`:

```
window.onload = function(){
  var campo = document.querySelector('#matricula');
  campo.addEventListener('keyup', function(){
  var matricula = campo.value.replace(/\D/g,""); // Remove o que não é digito
   matricula = matricula.replace(/(\d{4,5})(\d{1})$/,"$1-$2"); // 4 ou 5 dígitos a esquerda e 1 a direita
   console.log(matricula); // Mostra no Console
   this.value = matricula; // Insere o valor formatado no input
   if (campo.value.length < 5) { // Valida
     campo.classList.add("invalido");
   } else {
    campo.classList.remove("invalido");
  }
});
}
```

Comment: Se somente precisa alterar o formato, este é definido através da expressão regular presente no código. Recomendo, portanto, que estude expressões regulares, entenda o que foi feito e veja como definir o novo padrão.

Comment: nao estou a conseguir

Comment: Mais detalhes, por favor. O que não conseguiu? Leu sobre expressões regulares? Buscou entender o que foi feito? **Dica:** você pode utilizar o site https://regex101.com para testar suas expressões.

Comment: estou a tentar por o formato disto "replace(/(\d{4,5})(\d{1})$/,"$1-$2");" nisto 000-000-000 0

Comment: Ok, mas qual foi a sua tentativa? Seu último comentário foi basicamente um resumo do que está na pergunta e não acrescentou detalhes ao problema. Novamente, você sabe expressão regular? Se não, você as estudou? Se está tentando, coloque suas tentativas e descreva o resultado obtido, seja ele um erro ou apenas um retorno inesperado. Basicamente mostre qual foi o seu esforço em resolver o problema.

Comment: replace(/(\d{3})$(\d{3})$(\d{3})$/,"$1-$2");

Answer (score 1):

Creio que o limite seja de 13 caracteres na mascara, por causa do formato `000 000 000 0`, então comece aplicando `maxlength="13"` para evitar que o usuário digite muitas coisas.

No exemplo usei 2 regex:

```
/^(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d)+$/     <-- para extrair os numeros
/^(\d{3}) (\d{3}) (\d{3})(\d)+$/   <-- para validar após aplicar a mascara
```

Com regex:

```js
function MascaraFormato(campo)
{
    if (!campo) return;

    //extrai os numeros
    var formato = /^(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d)+$/;

    //valida o formato final
    var valido = /^(\d{3}) (\d{3}) (\d{3}) (\d)+$/;

    var timer,       // Para evitar multiplas execuções
        executando;  // Para preveinir o ".value = " disparar o evento

    function mascara()
    {
       if (executando) return;

       //Remove os numeros
       var matricula = campo.value.replace(/\D/g, "");
       
       //Extrai os numeros
       matricula = matricula.replace(formato, "$1 $2 $3 $4");

       //Bloqueia o ".value=" para evitar conflitos
       executando = true;

       //Testa se o formato foi extraido
       if (valido.test(matricula)) {
           campo.value = matricula;
           campo.classList.remove("invalido");

       //se não validar então limpa o campo
       } else {
           campo.value = ""; //Apaga o campo
           campo.classList.add("invalido");
       }

       // libera para voltar a aplicar a mascar, acaso ocorra outra alteração
       executando = false;
    }

    mascara(); //Executa a mascara quando a "página carrega"

    campo.addEventListener('input', function () {
         // Previne multiplas execuções
         if (timer) clearTimeout(timer);

         timer = setTimeout(mascara, 500);
    });
}

//Aplica a um campo
MascaraFormato(document.querySelector('#matricula'));

//Aplica a outro campo
MascaraFormato(document.querySelector('#outro'));
```

```html
<input id="matricula" maxlength="13">

<input id="outro" maxlength="13">
```

Uma forma mais simples seria usar `.match` para dividir a string de 3 em 3, depois com `substring` remover o que não é importante e para validar o formato basta checar se o tamanho da string é o mesmo do `maxlength="13"`, ou seja se for menor/diferente 13 significa que o valor digitado não é valido

Foi necessário uma regex só para dividir a string, mas no geral é mais simples, exemplo:

```js
function MascaraFormato(campo)
{
    if (!campo) return;

    var maxLength = parseInt( campo.getAttribute("maxlength") );

    var timer, executando;  // Para preveinir o ".value = " disparar o evento

    function mascara()
    {
       if (executando) return;

       //Remove os numeros
       var matricula = campo.value.replace(/\D/g, "");

       //Divide a string de 3 em 3 (array)
       matricula = matricula.match(/.{1,3}/g);

       if (matricula) {
            //com .join junta novamente aplicando espaços
            matricula = matricula.join(" ");

            //Limita a string ao tamanho de 13 caracteres, o mesmo do maxlength
            matricula = matricula.substring(0, maxLength);

            //Bloqueia o ".value=" para evitar conflitos
            executando = true;

            //Testa se o formato foi extraido, deve ter o tamanho exato
            if (matricula.length == maxLength) {
               campo.value = matricula;
               campo.classList.remove("invalido");

               executando = false;

               return; //Para a função neste ponto
            }
       }

       campo.value = ""; //Apaga o campo se for invalid
       campo.classList.add("invalido");

       executando = false;
    }

    mascara(); //Executa a mascara quando a "página carrega"

    campo.addEventListener('input', function () {
         // Previne multiplas execuções
         if (timer) clearTimeout(timer);

         timer = setTimeout(mascara, 500);
    });
}

//Aplica a um campo
MascaraFormato(document.querySelector('#matricula'));

//Aplica a outro campo
MascaraFormato(document.querySelector('#outro'));
```

```html
<input id="matricula" maxlength="13">

<input id="outro" maxlength="13">
```